VS Code not being able to recognize modules and constants imported from other scripts
I have a general question when working on larger projects using Visual Studio Code, where I want to avoid writing the same imports and defining constants in every python file. Let us say I have a project structure as follows:
project/
    helpers.py
    scripts/
        plot.py

In helpers.py, I import modules and define constants for plotting, such as
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

LINE_WIDTH = 2

As I want to avoid defining the line width on figures and importing matplotlib.pyplot in every script, I add the project folder to my python path, export $PYTHONPATH=/folder/to/project/:$PYTHONPATH, such that I in plot.py simply can write
from helpers import *

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,4,9], lw=LINE_WIDTH)
plt.savefig('figure.png')

In plot.py, VS Code believes that plt and LINE_WIDTH are not defined, but the scripts run fine, and I get the plot. Is there any way to make VS Code realize what have been imported from helpers.py, such that I do not have to remember all the specific variable namings when making new scripts?
I have tried to search for similar problems, but the closest I get is to problems related to relative imports.

I add a screenshot to visualize my problem:


I did some experiment but failed to reproduce your issue, and VS can recognize the import from helpers.py.What is your Python interpreter and what is your VSCode version and Python extension version?

Okay, thanks for looking into it. I use the following version: Python 3.10.11, VS code: 1.94.2, Python extension: v2024.16.1

Thanks for the info.I double checked my environmental which is identical to yours but I was unable to reproduce.Here's a workaround and check if this work for you:Add the helpers to python.analysis.extraPaths in settings and see if this can be mitigated.

One possible way to solve this is to create (in the same folder as your scripts) a new package folder. I named this folder "helper_package".
The content of the helper_package folder is a file named
__init__.py

with the content as follows:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
LINE_WIDTH = 2

You can put all of your common imports and variables in this.
Then, your plot.py file would look like this:
from helper_package import *

plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,4,9], lw=LINE_WIDTH)
plt.savefig('figure.png')

Please use the VSCode Python extension and the "Run Python File" run option. Not "Run Code".

Thanks for your suggestion, but I still face the same problem, namely that main.py does not see LINE_WIDTH as being defined, but main.py can still run without errors. I have added a screenshot of my problem for further clarification.
